# Probabilties to win prize after certain tries and attempts in wheel of fortune with $20$ fields

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There's a wheel of fortune with $20$ fields of equal size. $17$ fields are blank, $2$ are consolation prizes and $1$ field is the main prize.

With every attempt, John is allowed to spin the wheel of fortune $3$ times.

I want to find out the what the probabilities are that John

- wins a prize not later than $4$ tries
- wins the consolation prize at the end of an attempt
- wins the main prize at the beginning of an attempt

The probability, that John wins either the consolation prizes or the main prize is $\frac{3}{20}$.

Regarding the first case: The probability to get a prize in first four tries and in none of the other: ($\frac{3}{20} \cdot $ $\frac{17}{20}$) $\cdot 4 = 0.51 = 51\text{%}$

Regarding the second case: The probability to get a consolation prize is $\frac{2}{20}$. My guess is that $(\frac{18}{20}\cdot \frac{18}{20} \cdot \frac{2}{20}) \cdot 4 = 0.243 = 2.34 \text{%}$

Regarding the third case: $(\frac{1}{20} \cdot \frac{19}{20}\cdot \frac{19}{20}) \cdot 3 = 0.1353 = 13.53 \text{%} $

I have the feeling that none of them are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that "a try" means spinning the wheel once.

**First case:**

To win a prize not later than $4$ tries means not to win no prize in $4$ tries, so
$$
p=1-\left(1-\frac{3}{20}\right)^4\approx0.478=47.8\%
$$
**Second case:**

Winning a consolation prize at the end of an attempt means not winning anything in the first two tries, so
$$
p=\left(1-\frac{3}{20}\right)^2\cdot\frac{2}{20}\approx0.0723=7.23\%
$$

**Third case:**

To win the main prize at the beginning of an attempt means winning in the first try, so
$$
p=\frac{1}{20}=0.05=5\%
$$